# CodeIgniter News Tutorial delete

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and have completed the news tutorial. I am trying to add a delete and update button within the news section. I have seen your post on stackoverflow about the delete button on this tutorial but i still cant get it working.

Here is my coding that i have used from your post

news_model.php

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
 {
if ($slug === FALSE)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();
}

$query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_news()
{
$this->load->helper('url');

$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

$data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'text' => $this->input->post('text')
);

return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
 }


public function delete_news($id) {
$this->db->delete('news', array('id' => $id));
}

}





 CONTROLLER - news.php

   <?php
   class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}

public function view($slug)
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
    if (empty($data['news_item']))
{
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}

public function create()
   {
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
    $this->load->view('news/create');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
else
{
    $this->news_model->set_news();
    $this->load->view('news/success');
}
 }


   public function delete($id) {
   $this->news_model->delete_news($id);
   $this->load->helper('url');
   redirect('/www.shelim786.co.uk/CodeIgniter/news');
}




}




VIEWS - index.php 

<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

<h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
</div>
<p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
<p><a href="news/delete <?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">delete article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>

and ROUTING

  $route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
  $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
  $route['news'] = 'news';
  $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
  $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
  $route['news/delete/(:any)'] = 'news/delete/$1';
```

The problem i am having is that the news article in www.shelim786.co.uk/CodeIgniter/index.php/news
  doesnt delete when i click the delete button.

i would really appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks,

Shelim

Answer (score 0):

You don't have slash after the word 'delete' in the link. Your link gets displayed something like `http://www.shelim786.co.uk/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/delete 6`. Notice the space after 'delete'?

In your view, change the 'delete article' link line to this.

```
<p><a href="news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">delete article</a></p>
```

Notice the slash after 'delete'?

Comment: i have changed the delete article link to                       <p><a href="news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">delete article</a></p> http://shelim786.co.uk/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/news/delete/ok      and it comes up with a 404 error the articles still dont delete.    is there anything that i am doing wrong?

Comment: The controller word 'news' is being repeated in the link. This is because you are using the relative path while assigning the delete link. Try this for the delete link. `<?php site_url('news/delete/'.$news_item['slug']) ?>`. I am assuming you have url helper turned on.

Comment: In fact, I suggest you use `site_url()` for assigning all links, including view link. It cost me fair amount of time to figure out assigning links

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url() in /customers/5/f/b/shelim786.co.uk/httpd.www/CodeIgniter/application/views/news/index.php on line 8   this is the error i get when i assign link to   <?php site_url('news/delete/'.$news_item['slug']) ?> also i am new to codeigniter it is my first time using this so i am not sure how to turn on tinyurl

Comment: They are all in the manual. For url helper, take a look at [this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html). Or, you can open up `application/autoload.php`, and add 'url' to helper array to autoload url helper everytime. I highly recommend you go through the entire CodeIgniter manual at least once or twice. They have one of the best manual among MVC frameworks

Answer (score 0):

you should redirect your delete link **delete_news function**
 not **delete function** as the delete query is written there